# Is Genesis 20 a Flashback?

Tags: genesis, chronology

[Genesis 20](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2020&version=NIV) is the story of Abimelech, Abraham and Sarah. Are we to think that it take place after Genesis 19?

The immediate reason for asking - the immediate oddity - is that Sarah is very old at this point. However, there are a few other things: 1) God said that he would return and then open Sarah's womb in 18, however 20 begins with them leaving. 2) If 20 and 21 are temporary related then, it would be easy to think that Sarah's barrenness being cured was related to the same act - rather than the same actor - that cured the barrenness of Abimelech's wives and maids.

Could Genesis 20 be understood as happening earlier in Abraham's career? Introducing, for example, Abimelech closer to chapter 21 where peace is restored again between him and Abraham.

Comment: To be able to conceive Sarah had to start ovulating again. The hormonal changes caused her body to  rejuvenate. Women's attractiveness peak on the ovulation day.

„Why some women are more attractive than others has been the focus of many studies, and it has been repeatedly shown that features linked to immediate fertility (i.e. fertility at a given time) explain a large part of the variance in attractiveness.”
https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/jeb.13214

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It likely is a flashback, from the standpoint of the surrounding narrative, but so is much of this part of Genesis.

Comparing Genesis 12 with Genesis 20, many readers see them as a doublet, telling the same macro-story from different perspectives.

There are various documentary hypotheses for the origin of Genesis. Those who acknowledge the consistent Jewish belief that Moses was the author of Genesis suggest this means Moses was working with earlier, written sources. The evidence from [toledoths](http://www.talkgenesis.org/genesis-toledoth-mystery/) in Genesis is often used to support this view.

If this hypothesis is correct, Moses compiled Genesis from multiple earlier sources, which sometimes overlapped, with the result that several of the details in Genesis 20 were recorded more than once.

Moses' transition from one source to another introduces a pivot or flashback into the narrative (the same thing happens all the time in the Synoptic Gospels).

We may want to read these accounts in strict chronological sequence...but we risk imposing a modern literary convention on authors who were more interested in grouping material by theme than by chronology.